# Recursive match with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, recursive-regex

I need to split an expression with the following strings:

```
'with', 'select', 'from', 'where'
```

These will come in the sequence as I wrote. You may assume that each of the words will begin and end with word boundary.

I have done this without any problem. However, a new requirement has arrived. The `from` clause may contain a whole expression.

That means, the expression may be something like this:

```
with
   something
select
   something more
from
   with
      aaaa
   select
      bbbb      
   from
      [may be another expression]
   where
      the inner expression ends here
where
   the outer expression ends here
```

I need not split the inner expression.

Now the question is, is there a standard way to do something like that? Or I need to do it totally on my own manually?

I am not sure if it is important, my application is a C# one.

Comment: Is the data always going to be structured the same way, or can the with/select/from/where be in a different order?

Comment: @ChrisThompson same order always.

Comment: again here you can use http://VeParser.codeplex.com as I described in answer to your another question for parsing MDX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your use case is starting to get complicated enough that you might be better off investing the time and refactoring effort to use actual parsing utilities, rather than regular expressions. I'm not a C# programmer, so I can't help you much with suggestions, but googling for "C# parser libraries" yielded several links that looked promising.

If you only need up to a fixed level of nesting then I think it technically can be done in regular expressions, but it's going to get nasty. Probably the simplest approach would be to write an expression for each fixed level of nesting, and match them starting from the top until you get a hit. Ugly, but could work.

If there's no limit to the number of nested expressions that could be contained in a top-level expression, then regular expressions are not powerful enough to do this properly, and you'll need to look at parsing utilities. I would not attempt to write a parser on your own; there's almost certainly usable libraries that solve most of the tricky problems for you.

Comment: Thanks. Although there is a very small probability of nesting to more than 2 or 3 levels, it is not certain. Also, I really dont like NASTY regex (the one I have now is already a nasty one). I think I should go for a Parser. I will let you know if I find something suitable for my requirement :)

Comment: @Mohaimin Maybe come back and edit into your question what you end up finding, to help out anyone who lands on this question?

Comment: Of course. I have not found anything yet. I will do it as soon as I find something. I am searching.